# replace null values in one column based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains two columns one is called hits:

```
0      NaN
1      5.0
2      NaN
3      5.0
4      NaN
      ... 
295    NaN
296    NaN
297    NaN
298    NaN
299    NaN
```

and another column called converted:

```
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
      ..
345    0
346    1
347    0
348    1
349    0
```

what I want to do is to check if the row in the converted column has 0 or 1, if it has 0 the row in hits will have the value 6 ( it will replace the null value ) and if it has 1 it will replace the value with 9

I tried to use lambda but didnt give me a good result:

```
df['hits'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 9 if df['converted'] == 1 & df['hits'] == 'nan' else 6
,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change `df` to local variable `row`

```py
df['hits'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 9 if row['converted'] == 1 & pd.isnull(row['hits']) else 6
,axis=1)
```

Or with boolean masking

```py
df.loc[df['converted'].eq(0) & df['hits'].isna(), 'hits'] = 6
df.loc[df['converted'].eq(1), 'hits'] = 9
```

Comment: pd.isnan didnt work: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'isnan' and the second option it fill everything with 6 even if there is a value in hits ( so if there is a value in hits and converted equal 0 it also replaces the original value in hits to be 6) but i want to leave the original value